# y axis values not displaying on live candlestick plot with webscraped data

Tags: matplotlib, live-streaming, candlestick-chart

Program pull today's ES future's OHLC from cme website and next function create one day bar live plot.  Sometimes the y axis appears with current price values other times it appears with single digit values i.e. 1,2,3,4,5
ax_setylim fix the problem.  Neither does using another candlestick plot function.

```
import bleach
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

def get_data():

    req=requests.get('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/
    equity-index/us-    index/e-mini-sandp500.html')
    html=req.text
    htmlBS=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    Open=(htmlBS.find('td',    
    id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ESZ7_open")).contents
    Last=(htmlBS.find('td',  
    id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ESZ7_last")).contents
    High=(htmlBS.find('td',  
    id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ESZ7_high")).contents
    Low=(htmlBS.find('td',   
    id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ESZ7_low")).contents
    #use bleach module to clean strong tag from Low
    Open=bleach.clean(Open,tags=[],strip=True)
    Last=bleach.clean(Last,tags=[],strip=True)
    High=bleach.clean(High,tags=[],strip=True)
    Low=bleach.clean(Low,tags=[],strip=True)
    def clean_ohlc(x):
        x=x.replace('[','')
        x=x.replace(']','')

        return x
    Open=clean_ohlc(Open)
    High=clean_ohlc(High)
    Low=clean_ohlc(Low)
    Last=clean_ohlc(Last)

    OHLC=[Open,High,Low,Last]
    OHLC=[x.strip("'").strip('"') for x in OHLC]
    OHLC=[float(x) for x in OHLC]
    O=[]
    H=[]
    L=[]
    C=[]
    O.append(OHLC[0])
    H.append(OHLC[1])
    L.append(OHLC[2])
    C.append(OHLC[3])
    return O,H,L,C

style.use('ggplot')
fig=plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
def update(dummy):

    O,H,L,C= get_data()
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim([-.5,.5])
    candlestick2_ohlc(ax,O,H,L,C,width=.2,
    colorup='g',colordown='r',alpha=1.0)


anime=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval=25)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The output being sometimes correct and sometimes not suggests that there might be a problem getting the correct data from the webservice. There seems to be no sanity check on the received data, so it is well possible that the request is sometimes interrupted. Also, the repetition rate for requests at that service might be a bit too high.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case as I can print the values in the terminal everytime update function runs